# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-vista

I am developing an application in ASP.NET 3.5. i am exporting data to excel file using some interops dll's. earlier i have developed the applicaion in Windows 2003 Server.  at that time i could able to export the data to excel file. but recently i have upgraded my pc to Vista version.it is working fine in my localhost.

when i deploy the application in IIS iam getting this error. 
like "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.".
. please can any one let me know the resolution for this error.  please let me know asap......

Thanks & Regrads,  murali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to launch Excel as a COM server and don't have permissions to do so with the Network Service account that the ASP.Net process is running under.

This should help: http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx